# Blazor Button Onclick function submitting form

Tags: asp.net-core, modal-dialog, form-submit, blazor, buttonclick

I am facing strange issue while working on Blazor. I have a form for creating and editing records, on the same  form I have table with rows and columns. In one column I am rendering delete button as shown in the screenshot.When I click on delete button it shows modal box for confirmation.

[image]
Code : `<td><button @onclick="(() => ExecuteDelete(file.fileName))">x</button></td>`

When I click on this button, confirm modal box gets opened however behind the scene it is submitting the form and validation messages appear on the form. I have separate button for submitting the form.

Is this behavior correct ?? how to prevent this.

Could anyone please help in solving this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As per [spec](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/the-button-element.html), `<button>` elements are by default of `type="submit"` when placed within a form. Set delete buttons to explicit `type="button"`.

```html
<form>
  <button type="button" @onclick="(() => ExecuteDelete(file.fileName))">x</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Oups, I post at the same time than you, I delete

Comment: Thanks its working after explicitly specifying type=button